# SciChart went Maximum Plaid after updating to latest version

Tags: scichart

I have updated SciChart from version 3.31 to the latest version (4.2.2.9777) and for some reason it has caused every instance of a SciChart surface in my application to have this strange plaid background (see attached pictures).
While it is festive, I don't think the customer would approve.
I have no idea what's causing this. This is all we're using in terms of styling:
1. A Background:

```
 Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static theme:Brushes.BackgroundBrushKey}}"
```

2. A GridLinesPanelStyle:

   ```
      <Style x:Key="GridLinesPanelStyle"
           TargetType="{x:Type sci:GridLinesPanel}">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static theme:Brushes.BackgroundBrushKey}}" />
           <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
       </Style>
   ```

Neither of these should be causing this behavior. Any idea how I could fix this?

EDIT: I had to delete the images as I realized they may contain some of our client's proprietary information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very lol. >_<

Please set the `AxisBase.DrawMajorBands` property to turn off the maximum plaid effect  e.g.

```
<s:NumericAxis DrawMajorBands="False"/>
```

Also note you can change the color of the cross-hatch / plaid / tartan / banding effect on the chart background with `AxisBase.AxisBandsFill`, e.g.

```
<s:NumericAxis AxisBandsFill="0x33DDDDDD"/>
```

This should result in a more pleasing / subtle effect, like this

[image]